# CSS styles for position of html elements

Tags: css

I have scrollable div within that i have data and checkbox for each.Here i want to make my check box in one alignment,Can anyone suggest me how to do this.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="border : solid 2px #ff0000; background : #000000; color : #ffffff; padding : 4px; width : 200px; height : 50px; overflow : auto; ">
    test1   <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="ewew" style=" position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 0px; "/> <br />
    testing123<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="ewew"  style=" position: absolute; right: 199px; top: 0px; "/><br />
    testing45678<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="ewew"  style=" position: absolute; right: 199px; top: 0px; "/><br />
    </div>
</html>
```

Regards,

Raj

Comment: you want the checkboxes to align to each line of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gmedina/YBXrW/4/ ):

```
<form class="aForm">
    <label for="checkbox1"><input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" />test1</label>
    <label for="checkbox2"><input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" />test2</label>
    <label for="checkbox3"><input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" />test3</label>
</form>
<style>
.aForm {
    border : solid 2px #ff0000; 
    background : #000000; 
    color : #ffffff; 
    padding : 4px; 
    width : 200px; 
    height : 50px; 
    overflow : auto;
}

.aForm label {
    clear : right;
    display : block;
}

.aForm label input[type=checkbox] {
    float : right;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_inline

```
{display:inline}
```

UPDATE:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border : solid 2px #ff0000; background : #000000; color : #ffffff; padding : 4px; width : 200px; height : 50px; overflow : auto; ">
test1   <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="ewew" style="float: right"/> <br />
testing123<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="ewew"  style="float: right "/><br />
testing45678<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="ewew"  style="float: right "/><br />
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: @John: If you see the above code,i want to place checkbox alignment in fixed location .

Comment: Ok... the update above will "float" the checkboxes to the right of the scrollable div.

Comment: @John:I tried updated code,still checkboxes are not in alignment.

Comment: I'm running the test code in http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_inline in a Firefox browser.

Comment: Even i tried with Mozilla,it looks good,Is it float:right wont work with IE,Is there any other alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `<input>` tag BEFORE your label text like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="ewew" style="float: right"/>test1<br />
```

That should fix the float problem in IE.